# A confusing sentence from a text-based game

Tags: meaning, grammar

The context

"It was a clear cold morning, my child, and Hareetha knew she was doomed. Behemoth Mountain lay in ruins, but I could hear her laughing. ***For was her god not the god of ruin?"***

This context is from a text-based game made by ***Choice of Games***. I am confused about the meaning of the last sentence. It might be an easy sentence because I know the meaning of every word. But I am not an English native speaker so I cannot understand the real meaning of it.

Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: This is my first time using this website, didn't expect answers so quick, really appreciate you all for explaining it for me.

Comment: If there’s one answer that you’ve found really useful you can ‘accept’ it by clicking the green tick to the left of the answer. That brings that one to the top. You can only accept one answer, though.

Comment: All the answers help me a lot ：)  and Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Please consider whether your question suits our English Language Learners site better, Bobpatrick..

Comment: It's a weird sentence, old fashioned poetic style. "For" = "Because", "was her god not" = poetically old-timey "wasn't her god".

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I wonder is there any criterion for these two sectors or just as per personal preference? Actually I used this one because it is titled English language and usage

Comment: Though 'But I am not an English native speaker so I cannot understand the real meaning of it.' is not definitive, I'd take it as a serious indicator.

Answer (score 2):

> For was her god not the god of ruin?

This sentence is a rhetorical question – while it appears to be a question, its purpose is to be a statement explaining Hareetha's actions. The fact that Hareetha is laughing at the destruction of Behemoth Mountain appears strange, but the speaker is using this rhetorical question to remind us that she worships a god of ruin, which explains her behavior.

We could rephrase that sentence in a clearer, but less poetic, way as:

> That made sense because her god was the god of ruin.

Answer (score 2):

> For was her god not the god of ruin?

While the sentence is rhetorical, it also has an almost archaic structure to it.

It can be paraphrased as:

> Wasn't this because her god was the god of ruin?

The use of *for* implies a reason for the fact that the mountain lay in ruins.

Answer (score 0):

**For was her god not the god of ruin?**

This is fine.  Do you understand the question "Was her god not the god of ruin?"  When I put **For** on the beginning, I assert that the answer (yes) to this rhetorical question explains why she was laughing.